# Using switch case with radio change

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on the demo below. Why am I getting `undefined`  when I select the `No` option, but selecting the `Yes` is returning `true`?

```js
var unew;
$('input:radio[name=radios]').on('change', function () {
    var val = $('input:radio[name=radios]:checked').val();
     console.log(val);
    switch (val) {
        case 'false':
               console.log(unew);
               unew = false;
        break;            
        case 'true':
               unew = true;
               console.log(unew);
        break;

    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <div class="col-md-4 mb-4">
          <label for="booking-age">Are you Agree</label>
                    <div  class="p-0">
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle my-1" data-toggle="buttons">
                    <label for="radios-0" class="btn btn-secondary rounded-0">
                      <input type="radio" name="radios" id="radios-0" value="true" >
                      Yes
                    </label>
                    <label for="radios-1" class="btn btn-secondary rounded-0">
                      <input type="radio" name="radios" id="radios-1" value="false" >
                      No 
                    </label>
                  </div>
                </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Write console.log after unew = false

Answer (score 1):

made a few changes

notice the default case in the switch statement, also ensure that on of the checked box have a default value of true for the checked property.

```js
var unew;
$('input:radio[name=radios]').on('input', function () {
 var val = $(this).val();
  console.log(val);
 switch (val) {
  case 'false':
               unew = false;
  break;            
  case 'true':
               unew = true;
  break;
        default:
              /* Neither of the radio buttons are selected/checked*/
              /* Handle it your way */
        break;

 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <div class="col-md-4 mb-4">
          <label for="booking-age">Are you Agree</label>
     <div  class="p-0">
 <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle my-1" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label for="radios-0" class="btn btn-secondary rounded-0">
          <input type="radio" name="radios" id="radios-0" value="true" >
          Yes
        </label>
        <label for="radios-1" class="btn btn-secondary rounded-0">
          <input type="radio" name="radios" id="radios-1" value="false" checked="true">
          No 
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use an `if...else` condition instead of `switch...case`. Also, in the change event, the value can be accessed by `$(this).val()`

```js
var unew;
$('input:radio[name=radios]').on('change', function() {
  var val = $(this).val();
  console.log(val);
  if (val == 'true') { // case 'true' 
    unew = true;
  } else { //case 'false'   
    unew = false;
  }
  console.log(unew);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-4 mb-4">
  <label for="booking-age">Are you Agree</label>
  <div class="p-0">
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle my-1" data-toggle="buttons">
      <label for="radios-0" class="btn btn-secondary rounded-0">
          <input type="radio" name="radios" id="radios-0" value="true" >
          Yes
        </label>
      <label for="radios-1" class="btn btn-secondary rounded-0">
          <input type="radio" name="radios" id="radios-1" value="false" >
          No 
        </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```